# Rails calling create method from same controller instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a few hours with something that is probably very easy.

I have a nested model

```
  resources :grades do
    resources :students
  end
```

So I defined

```
before_action :set_grade, except: [:mass_input]
```

to my students_controller

```
  def set_grade
    @grade = Grade.find(params[:grade_id])
  end
```

I'm very good with this, the problem is that now I'm using another action that takes :grade_id from another source, so I cant use set_grade,  instead I'm passing the id with javascript. Works.

My problem appears here, when I try to call to create method, I'm probably doing it wrong ..

```
def mass_input
    @grade = Grade.find(@data['grade'])
    @data = JSON.parse(params[:form_data])
    #is this create way ok or I'm overriding???
    Student.create(:rut => @data['mass_students'][1][0], :nombre => @data['mass_students'][1][1], :apellido =>  @data['mass_students'][1][2])
end
```

This is my create action

```
def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)
    @grade.students << @student
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.save
        format.html { redirect_to school_grade_path(@grade.school,@grade), notice: 'Alumno creado con éxito.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

By this way code works but this line is not working

```
@grade.students << @student
```

@grade is not passing from mass_input to create. I think I'm not calling create properly but I cant find how to do it , because is not redirecting neither

My mass_input action is working by this way

```
 def mass_input
    @grade = Grade.find(@data['grade'])
    @data = JSON.parse(params[:form_data])
    Student.create(:rut => @data['mass_students'][1][0], :nombre => @data['mass_students'][1][1], :apellido =>  @data['mass_students'][1][2])
    grade.students << student
    respond_to do |format|
      if student.save
        format.html { redirect_to school_grade_path(grade.school,grade), notice: 'Alumno creado con éxito.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: student }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

but I think is AWFUL, I must use my own create action

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh... From my point of view you are doing smth strange... The fast solution for your issue would be smth like this:

1) Rewrite before action in a new way:

```
before_action :set_grade
```

And method set_grade:

```
def set_grade
  @grade = Grade.find(params[:grade_id].presence || @data['grade'])
end
```

2) Set method for student params

```
def student_params
  data = JSON.parse(params[:form_data])['mass_students']
  #Transform data to be student params. For ex:
  data.map{|_key, info| {:rut => info[0], :nombre => info[1], :apellido => info[2]}}    
end
```

3) Rewrite mass_input method

```
def mass_input
  respond_to do |format|
    if (@students = @grade.students.create(student_params).all?(&:persisted?)
      #some actions when everything is great.
    else
      #some actions if not of them valid (maybe redirect & show info about not created students)
    end
  end
end
```

But you should definetly read more rails guides... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: Looks weird because this mass_input action receives a handsontable grid with the students data . I'm trying with the first row,  but after I make this work I will have to do a each to iterate the grid object and insert all the records.

Comment: What you will do if one student is valid and other one is not valid? What should happen in this case?

Comment: I'm thinking about validating by js , and use find or create for FK managing (grades - students is a many to many relation) .. I'm already using student_params in the single insert form.  Do I need to replicate the create method instead of just calling it ? I will try with your set_grade proposal

Comment: I've modified answer to apply multiple creation.

Comment: you cann't use create method because of two reasons:
1) It suitable only for one model (not multiple model creation)
2) Student.create - this will not call controller action it will call class method 'create' on model (and you should not operate with respond_to in model methods). 
You are mixing lots of different things together...

Comment: That  last you said is key for me,  so I'm not calling create action from controller with Student.create, and thats why is not doing grade.students << student , right? .. now how I manage this 2 student_param types?? (for individual input by form , and for massive input by grid). Thanks!!

Comment: My students_params looks like : 

 params.require(:student).permit(:nombre, :apellido, :rut)

Comment: You should just use different method names) For example  students_params for individual & multiple_students_params - for multiple use. If you still want to re-use create method you should extract common code in separate method (For example create_student & pass student params as an argument(then you can call this method from create & from mass_input), but I do not see any reason for this it will be not clear to read & slower)

Comment: Said nothing, your solution is clean and works like a charm! , the only thing is that redirect is not working but thats another topic. regards!

Comment: My mistake it should be 'info' in map's block. Can you pleas show this value? JSON.parse(params[:form_data])['mass_students']
I think  data.map{|_key, info| {:rut => info[0], :nombre => info[1], :apellido => info[2]}} will do what you want.

Comment: Yes , now works , problem is that is getting the last empty row so Student.last shows nil on all atributes

Comment: Just use .select to escape such rows: data.map{|_key, info| {:rut => info[0], :nombre => info[1], :apellido => info[2]}}.select{|attrs| attrs[:rut].present?}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I couldn't comment it. So I can just post a reply, it is not an complete answer though.  In the student controller
Try to use

```
@student = @grade.students.new
```

or

```
@student = Student.new
@student.grade = @grade or @student.grade_id = params[:grade_id]
```

So when you do @student.save, you won't need to do the line below, and it will still work

```
@grade.students << @student
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on rails has conventions you should follow to simplify lots of things. The first thing I see here is that in your `def mass_input`, you are using

```
Student.create(...)
```

The method `create`, as it says, creates an object but also saves it into database. So you should have `new` instead of `create` because `new` does not save it to database, just instantiates it:

```
@student = Student.new
```

...inside `def mass_input`, and by default the submit action in your view will take your object to the create method (if the object is new it goes to create, other way it goes to update, thanks to Rails). For this you could take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

About the line `@grade.students << @student`, I assume you are intending to add the newly created student to his grade. See this example of usage of nested resources when trying to create, edit or destroy http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources. In any case, nested resources implies this:

```
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :grade
end
```

So, in your model `Student` you should have a column to store the `Grade` of that student. And then in your params you should receive the actual grade and store it in the `grade_id` inside your `@student`.

If something is not clear, I suggest you to take a look at the nested resources guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

---

As a commentary, `<<` is used to add "things" to the end of an array, i.e. if you want to quickly store in an array some info you use:

```
 array = []
 Student.all.each do |s|
   array << s.name
 end
```

It will store in the `array` all the names of your students. Obviously there is a simpler way to do this by doing this:

```
Student.pluck(:name)
```